# How to fix "Program type already present: com.reactlibrary.BuildConfig" after installing Appodeal

Tags: react-native, appodeal

Is there anyone who tried to install the Appodeal? I'm trying to install the Appodeal to our React Native 0.60 project but I encountered this error "Program type already present: com.reactlibrary.BuildConfig". I can't find which, where is something wrong.

Here's the plugin that I used.
https://github.com/appodeal/react-native-appodeal

Here's the error that I got:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Error while merging dex archives:
> > Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> > Program type already present: com.reactlibrary.BuildConfig
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
> at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
> at runOnAllDevices (D:\Projects\Mobile\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-androi
> ```
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
> Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 Note:
> Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
> with -Xlint:deprecation for details. D8: Program type already present:
> com.reactlibrary.BuildConfig
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Error while merging dex archives:
> > Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> > Program type already present: com.reactlibrary.BuildConfig
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
> at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
> at runOnAllDevices (D:\Projects\Mobile\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
> at buildAndRun (D:\Projects\Mobile\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
> at then.result (D:\Projects\Mobile\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
> at <anonymous>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
> ```

Comment: It's a shame this hasn't been resolved. I've got exactly the same issue with React Native.